# nginx + php-fpm - 502 Bad Gateway when rewrite with dash

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, php

I use nginx with php-fpm for my webserver and I have a little trouble with the rewrite system.

So when I want to access to page like /dashboard or /api/info it works correctly. But when I want to access to page with dash in URL like /dashboard/global-infos, I get an error 502 (Bad Gateway).

My configuration for rewriting is:

```
    rewrite ^/index\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}

rewrite_log on;
```

When I read log, I do not have log on rewriting, only :

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 176.190.XXX.XXX, server: domain.com, request: "GET /dashboard/global-infos
```

Hope you can help me, have a good day !